# length option for local blast

Tags: awk, blast

I have a relatively large blastn output file. As there is no option to specify minimum nucleotide length of the query sequence, my idea is to search for it after the blast run using awk.

an example of the file is this:

```
> abc
Length=4553119

 Score = 273 bits (302),  Expect = 3e-74
 Identities = 151/151 (100%), Gaps = 0/151 (0%)
 Strand=Plus/Plus

Query  1        CCCACATCGAACTCGACGGTGACCATTCCCATGTTGCGCCGGGACGCCGAGTAGACGTGC  60
                ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
Sbjct  4297151  CCCACATCGAACTCGACGGTGACCATTCCCATGTTGCGCCGGGACGCCGAGTAGACGTGC  4297210

Query  61       TTGACCCCCGGAATTTCGCTCATGATGCGCTCGAGCGGCTGCATCGCCAGGTTCGACACC  120
                ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
Sbjct  4297211  TTGACCCCCGGAATTTCGCTCATGATGCGCTCGAGCGGCTGCATCGCCAGGTTCGACACC  4297270

Query  121      TGCTGCGCGGAGGCCCCCGGGTACTGCACCA  151
                |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
Sbjct  4297271  TGCTGCGCGGAGGCCCCCGGGTACTGCACCA  4297301


 Score = 28.3 bits (30),  Expect = 1.7
 Identities = 15/15 (100%), Gaps = 0/15 (0%)
 Strand=Plus/Minus

Query  97     GGCTGCATCGCCAGG  111
              |||||||||||||||
Sbjct  63261  GGCTGCATCGCCAGG  63247
```

using awk, I am searching for for all lines that contain `Identities = [>=50]`

```
awk 'Identities =  >= 50'
```

I do not care about the rest of the line (from `/151 (100%)` on).

but I get a syntax error, so how do I put the "greater and equal than" in there?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I want a value greater than 50, the 14 was only an example; I want all the strings with 50/[xx]

Comment: sorry, I changed my question accordingly

Comment: When you say `I do not care about the rest of the line (from /151 (100%) on).` do you mean you don't want it tested as part of the input comparison or you don't want it printed as part of the output or both or something else? [edit] your question to show the exact expected output to help clarify. English requirements are useful but ambiguous and vague - complete concrete examples are very necessary!

Comment: ok actually my idea to solve the problem was a different one than you suggested... anyways my ultimate goal is to use this search pattern and print the 5th line (counting from the line `Identities`, so the line starting with `Sbjct`) if the condition (>=50) is met

Comment: Just say in your question what it is you're actually trying to do with concise, testable sample input and expected output and be clear if you want to print the line starting with `Sbjct` or the 5 line after `Identify` or if either criteria works equally or something else. It sounds like what you want is probably absolutely trivial if you can just state clearly what it is.

Comment: sorry for that, I did not want to get the full solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '/Identities =/ && ($3+0)>=50' file
 Identities = 151/151 (100%), Gaps = 0/151 (0%)
```